# Android Camera cannot open

Tags: android, camera, release

I have a different scenario. I have the camera input connected to the android device. As per the steps given, I have initialized the camera object and the display is working perfectly as excepted.

I have separate code for receiving the camera disconnect information from the underlying linux kernel. In that case, I have to close the camera. Again, if the camera is connected back, I have to make the display resume back.

Scenario 1:
When the camera disconnect information is obtained, I tried following functions

```
Cameraobject.setPreviewCallBack(null);
CameraObject.stopPreview();
CameraObject.release();
```

Problem: The control loops within these functions.

Scenario 2:
I have commented the above lines. Instead, in the code section which gets executed when the camera gets connected again I have called them.

```
Cameraobject.setPreviewCallBack(null);
CameraObject.stopPreview();
CameraObject.release();
Cameraobject = Camera.open(cameraID);
```

Problem: Here it gets a runtime error. Could not be connected to camera service.

Comment: Can you post the runtime error which you get?

Comment: Have you tried running the callback with Handler and Runnable? Could be some thread timing issue, since you are getting the message from kernel here and the system might need some delay to run the release open code again.

Comment: 01-01 10:49:10.351: W/System.err(557): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
01-01 10:49:10.351: W/System.err(557):  at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
01-01 10:49:10.351: W/System.err(557):  at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:345)
01-01 10:49:10.351: W/System.err(557):  at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:303)

Comment: Here are some good posts about camera usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371692/fail-to-connect-to-camera-service

Answer (score 1):

Are you added appropriate permissions defined in your manifest.?

```
android.permission.CAMERA
```

Comment: Permissions should not be a problem: "I have initialized the camera object and the display is working perfectly as excepted."

Answer (score 0):

add in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```