# capturing vide on android gives runtimeException start faild: -19 on -version 4.0.1 galaxy s 2

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture, runtimeexception, android-mediarecorder

Update1: now code makes this errors after change code to bellow:

```
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at fun.audios.maker.VideoRecorderActivity.startRecording(VideoRecorderActivity.java:237)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at fun.audios.maker.VideoRecorderActivity.access$9(VideoRecorderActivity.java:146)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at fun.audios.maker.VideoRecorderActivity$1.onClick(VideoRecorderActivity.java:88)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3620)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:107)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14292)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
02-20 10:43:13.624: W/System.err(5494):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

code changed to :

```
  private void startRecording()  
   {

    mrec = new MediaRecorder(); 
     mCamera.unlock();
     mrec.setCamera(mCamera); 

     mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
     mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

     mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

     mrec.setVideoFrameRate(15); //this line removed comment
     mrec.setVideoSize(720, 480);

     Method[] methods =   mrec.getClass().getMethods();
     for (Method method: methods){
            try
            {
                if(method.getName().equals("setAudioEncodingBitRate"))
                {
                   method.invoke(mrec,12200);
                }
                else if(method.getName().equals("setVideoEncodingBitRate"))
                {
                    method.invoke(mrec, 3000000);
                }
                else if(method.getName().equals("setAudioSamplingRate"))
                {
                    method.invoke(mrec,8000);
                }
                else if(method.getName().equals("setVideoFrameRate"))
                {
                    method.invoke(mrec,24);
                }

            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (InvocationTargetException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (RuntimeException e) 
             {
                Log.d("errorrrrrrrrr runtime111111111", "okkkkkkkkkk");
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }

     mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
     mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

     mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());   
     mrec.setOrientationHint(90); 

     mrec.setOutputFile(Videopath);

     try 
     {
         mrec.prepare();

     } 
     catch (IllegalStateException e) 
     {
       //  releaseRecorder();
      //   return false;
     } 
     catch (IOException e) 
     {
      //   releaseRecorder();
       //  return false;
     }
     catch (RuntimeException e) 
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
      //  return false;
     }


     try
     {
         mrec.start(); 
     }
     catch (RuntimeException e) 
     {
        Log.d("errorrrrrrrrr runtime44444444444", "okkkkkkkkkk");

        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
      //  return false;
        Log.d("errorrrrrrrrr 33333333333", "okkkkkkkkkk");

     }
     isRecording=true;
    // return true;
 }
```

and permissons add like this:

```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
       <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
       <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
       <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>this is my
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
I am new in android and have this code for capturing video.most part of code is according android developer guide user in Camera. But gives me exception runtimeException
: Fail to connect to camera service.
which line of my code has error? whole logs is here:

```
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
W/System.err(4991):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:344)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:321)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at fun.audios.maker.VideoRecorderActivity.startRecording(VideoRecorderActivity.java:144)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at fun.audios.maker.VideoRecorderActivity.access$9(VideoRecorderActivity.java:142)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at fun.audios.maker.VideoRecorderActivity$1.onClick(VideoRecorderActivity.java:86)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3620)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:107)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14292)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 05:42:56.054: D/errorrrrrrrrr runtime(4991): okkkkkkkkkk
```

this is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recorder_video);
        InitializeUI();
//button for start and stop recording calls
}


private void startRecording()  
{
    //mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mrec = new MediaRecorder(); 
     mCamera.unlock();
     mrec.setCamera(mCamera); 

     mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
     mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

     mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

   //  mrec.setVideoFrameRate(15);
     mrec.setVideoSize(720, 480);

     Method[] methods =   mrec.getClass().getMethods();
     for (Method method: methods){
            try
            {
                if(method.getName().equals("setAudioEncodingBitRate"))
                {
                   method.invoke(mrec,12200);
                }
                else if(method.getName().equals("setVideoEncodingBitRate"))
                {
                    method.invoke(mrec, 3000000);
                }
                else if(method.getName().equals("setAudioSamplingRate"))
                {
                    method.invoke(mrec,8000);
                }
                else if(method.getName().equals("setVideoFrameRate"))
                {
                    method.invoke(mrec,24);
                }

            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (InvocationTargetException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (RuntimeException e) 
             {
                Log.d("errorrrrrrrrr runtime111111111", "okkkkkkkkkk");
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }

     mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
     mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

     mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());   
     mrec.setOrientationHint(90); 

     mrec.setOutputFile(Videopath);

     try 
     {
         mrec.prepare();

     } 
     catch (IllegalStateException e) 
     {
       //  releaseRecorder();
      //   return false;
     } 
     catch (IOException e) 
     {
      //   releaseRecorder();
       //  return false;
     }
     catch (RuntimeException e) 
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
      //  return false;
     }


     try
     {
         mrec.start(); 
     }
     catch (RuntimeException e) 
     {
        Log.d("errorrrrrrrrr runtime44444444444", "okkkkkkkkkk");

        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
      //  return false;
        Log.d("errorrrrrrrrr 33333333333", "okkkkkkkkkk");

     }
     isRecording=true;
    // return true;
 }
 //-------------------------------------------------------------

/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance()
{
    Camera c = null;
    try 
    {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------
private void stopRecording() 
{

    if(isRecording)
    {
    mrec.stop();  // stop the recording
    releaseRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
    btnlistToggle.setEnabled(true);
    isRecording=false;
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------

// release the recorder after recording
    private void releaseRecorder() 
    {

        if (mrec != null) {
            mrec.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
            mrec.release(); // release the recorder object
            mrec = null;
            mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
        }
   }
//-------------------------------------------------------------

    // release the camera after recording
    private void releaseCamera() 
    {

         if (mCamera != null)
         {
             mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
             mCamera = null;
         }
    }
     public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) 
{

    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (holder.getSurface() == null)
    {
      // preview surface does not exist
      return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try 
    {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here

    // start preview with new settings
    try 
    {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      //  Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
 //-------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
{

     if (mCamera != null)
       {
          Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
          mCamera.setParameters(params);
          mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
          try 
          {
             mCamera .setPreviewDisplay(holder);
             mCamera .startPreview();
           } 
          catch (IOException e) 
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

       }

       else
       {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         VideoRecorderActivity.this.finish();
       }


}
 //-------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
{

}
      protected void onPause() 
 {
    datasource.close();
    super.onPause();
    //if(mrec != null)
    //{
      releaseRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
      releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
    //}
}

 private void InitializeUI()
 {


       // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mCamera.lock();

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        mToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleRecordingButton);
 }
```

and this is my xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:orientation="vertical" 
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:background="@drawable/bg_header_footers">
              <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:paddingTop="2dp">
                   <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvSetNameRecorder"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" 
                        android:text="Make your Video!" 
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
             </LinearLayout>

              <LinearLayout 
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">  
                  <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >       
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvTimer1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                         android:textColor="@color/Lightgray"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textStyle="bold" 
                        android:text="00:00:00"/>                  
                     </LinearLayout>    

                  <LinearLayout
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                       android:paddingLeft="10dp">     
                    <ImageView
                           android:id="@+id/imgcheshmak1"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:src="@drawable/cheshmak" 
                           android:visibility="gone"/>
                    </LinearLayout> 
            </LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout 
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="1">
              <SurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </LinearLayout>


            <TableLayout
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
                    android:id="@+id/linerlistandback"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_gravity="center" 
                     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content">  

                    <TableRow 
                         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
                         android:gravity="center" 
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                         android:layout_width="match_parent">

                         <LinearLayout 
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                              android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:paddingRight="2dp">   
                           <Button
                               android:id="@+id/btnToggleListVideo"
                               android:layout_width="0dp"
                               android:layout_height="40dp"
                               android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
                               android:drawableLeft="@drawable/listtttt" 
                               android:paddingLeft="30dp" 
                               android:paddingRight="20dp" 
                               android:layout_weight="1" 
                               android:textSize="20dp" android:text="List"/>
                         </LinearLayout>

                         <LinearLayout
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                             android:layout_width="0dp" 
                             android:layout_weight="1" android:paddingLeft="2dp">
                             <ToggleButton
                                 android:id="@+id/toggleRecordingButton"
                                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                                 android:textOff="Start"
                                 android:textOn="Stop" 
                                 android:background="@drawable/selector_button" 
                                 android:layout_height="40dp" 
                                 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/camera" 
                                 android:paddingLeft="30dp" 
                                 android:paddingRight="20dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="20dp"/>
                         </LinearLayout>

                      </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions in your manifest?

Comment: yeah @steven I add these permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

Comment: Try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371692/fail-to-connect-to-camera-service

Comment: @Steven this link couldnt help me.

Comment: what can i do @Steven ? this is nessesary for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found solution. I remove a part of my code and then start faild error didnt happen.
i change code to this :

```
private void startRecording()  
    {
         mrec = new MediaRecorder(); 
         mCamera.unlock();

         mrec.setCamera(mCamera); 

         mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
         mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

         mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

         mrec.setVideoFrameRate(15);
         mrec.setVideoSize(720, 480);

         mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
         mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);

         mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());   
         mrec.setOrientationHint(90); 

         mrec.setOutputFile(Videopath);

         try 
         {
             mrec.prepare();
             mrec.start(); 
         } 
         catch (IllegalStateException e) 
         {
           //  releaseRecorder();
          //   return false;
         } 
         catch (IOException e) 
         {
          //   releaseRecorder();
           //  return false;
         }
         catch (RuntimeException e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
          //  return false;
         }

     }
```

i guess parameters values for invoke method has issue while setting.If you have some better resplonse revolving making better quality like my invoke method post your responses for help to me and other people read this post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have the right permissions to use the camera service.
Try adding this to your manifest file:

EDIT: It works for me! I used the same code as you, I know that I've said it before but check your permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: Sorry @Steven didn't mean to steal your comment. I saw it as soon as I posted the answer.

Comment: I have permision which is needed.

Comment: Can you post your layout.xml?

Comment: So when does it give you an Exception?? Are you able to see the preview on SurfaceView? I just tried it on my HTC One and it shows me the preview..

Comment: yeah.i can see . but when click start makes fail to camera service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering that you add proper permission.
you have to **add permission** in menifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

When you using camera, if camera is connected with another app, then you can't use camera(it maybe cause Fail to connect camera service).

So, you have to make sure **only your app use camera service**.

I hope you fix your error

Bye!

Comment: I have permission which is needed.

Comment: what can i do for resloving my problem.I need this for now nessesary.

Answer (score 0):

According to your crash log

```
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
W/System.err(4991):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:344)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:321)
02-20 05:42:56.054: W/System.err(4991):     at fun.audios.maker.VideoRecorderActivity.startRecording(VideoRecorderActivity.java:144)
```

, the camera couldn't be opened successfully in MediaRecorder.

You can read the Android tutorial - [capture video](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video)
Code:

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    // Step 4: Set output file
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If the code can't work, it should be your ROM issue.

Comment: I dont want facing-front camera! and also I now try you told. same exception gives me!!

Comment: what can i do @yushulx ? this is nessesary for me

Comment: can you try your code on other devices? or emulator?

Comment: on real device. galaxy s 2 version 4.0.1

Comment: on sumsong version 2.2 on real device run correctly

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can refer to Google's tutorial to have a try

Comment: what do i do with my ROM @yushulx ? cuz code dosnt worked. I write my code exactly according your code.

Comment: Upgrade your system version, or flash other ROMs, such as CyanogenMod. Sometimes, the standard Android APIs can't work well on some devices. The compatibility is really a big problem of Android. I ever tried my own program on different smartphones with different ROMs, they performed differently.